# Get Android API Level in pre-build script

Tags: android, visual-studio, batch-file, xamarin.android

I need to replace a file based on the Android target version in a Xamarin Android app's pre-build event. Target version of the app is placed within the manifest file.

[image]

Any way I can perform the check in a batch script?

Comment: According to your description, you want to get some data from Pre-build event command line in Xamarin.android project?

Comment: I want to reader the value of android:targetSdkVersion in the manifest file in the pre-build event

Answer (score 0):

Here is the end result after hours of search:

```
find /c "android:targetSdkVersion=""27""" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" >NUL
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
    xcopy "$(ProjectDir)libOreo\armeabi-v7a\libwedsa23.so" "$(ProjectDir)lib\armeabi-v7a" /Y /R
    xcopy "$(ProjectDir)libOreo\x86\libwedsa23.so" "$(ProjectDir)lib\x86" /Y /R
    goto done
:notfound
    SET ERRORLEVEL=0
    xcopy "$(ProjectDir)libJellyBeans\armeabi-v7a\libwedsa23.so" "$(ProjectDir)lib\armeabi-v7a" /Y /R
    xcopy "$(ProjectDir)libJellyBeans\x86\libwedsa23.so" "$(ProjectDir)lib\x86" /Y /R
    goto done
:done
```

I ended up using simple string search. If the manifest file contains 27 as target version I interpret it as Android Oreo version and copy the necessary files

Comment: Just a suggestion: you should never set the ERRORLEVEL value. It is a system-defined variable you must not modify (in the same way as %DATE%, %TIME%, %RANDOM% and other variables)